# Print centroid of volume of instance in Abaqus

Tags: python, nodes, abaqus, centroid

I created a model in Abaqus using Python and I want to use the node nearest to the centroid volume in my Python code. However I can never find how to use this, only how to manually find the volume centroid in Abaqus (Tools --> Query --> Mass properties and select instance). And then I can use this point to find the nearest node. Is there code available to script the tools-->query-->mass properties part?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get query related commands for the assembly in Chapter `6.1 Assembly Object` of Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide. Unfortunately, the query commands are not recorded in `.rpy` file. However, one should always check Reference Guide for the related object.

For getting mass properties, you can use the following command:

```
# Accessing the instance object
inst = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1']

# Getting the mass properties of the part instance
mp = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties(regions=[inst,])
print(mp)
```

The mass property variable, `mp`, is dictionary object. When you print it:

```
{'volume': 74912600.0, 'massFromMassPerUnitSurfaceArea': None, 'area': None, 'volumeCentroid': (63.5161468164234, 500.0, 2578.95903759848), 'warnings': (MISSING_DENSITY,), 'momentOfInertia': (None, None, None, None, None, None), 'centerOfMass': (None, None, None), 'mass': None, 'areaCentroid': (None, None, None)}
```

Then you can use the `getClosest` command to find the nearest node.

```
inst.nodes.getClosest(mp['volumeCentroid'])
```